# why do I get preg_replace() error when submitting a post form in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, preg-replace

I have built a simple application laravel 4. I have scaffolding setup for adding posts which seems to be working fine. I have setup Stapler and image uploading package. When I setup to use single image uploads its pretty good and it works a charm. I recently looked at the docs [here](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/stapler#examples)

It states that you can do multiple uploads so I went about doing it as explained in the docs. Here are my coded pages:

Post.php model:

```
<?php

class Post extends Eloquent {
    use Codesleeve\Stapler\Stapler;
    protected $guarded = array();

    // A user has many profile pictures.
    public function galleryImages(){
        return $this->hasMany('GalleryImage');
    }

    public static $rules = array(
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required'
    );

    public function __construct(array $attributes = array()) {
    $this->hasAttachedFile('picture', [
        'styles' => [
            'thumbnail' => '100x100',
            'large' => '300x300'
        ],
        // 'url' => '/system/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
        'default_url' => '/:attachment/:style/missing.jpg'
    ]);

    parent::__construct($attributes);
    }

}
```

PostsController.php

```
/**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        $input = Input::all();
        $validation = Validator::make($input, Post::$rules);

        if ($validation->passes())
        {
            $this->post->create($input);

            return Redirect::route('posts.index');
        }
        $post = Post::create(['picture' => Input::file('picture')]);

        foreach(Input::file('photos') as $photo)
        {
            $galleryImage = new GalleryImage();             
            $galleryImage->photo = $photo;                   
            $user->galleryImages()->save($galleryImage);    
        }


        return Redirect::route('posts.create')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validation)
            ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
    }
```

This has save functions and other functions inside it too.

GalleryImage.php gallery image model to use in the post controller

```
<?php

class GalleryImage extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

    public function __construct(array $attributes = array()) {

    $this->hasAttachedFile('photo', [
        'styles' => [
            'thumbnail' => '300x300#'
        ]
    ]);

    parent::__construct($attributes);
    }

    // A gallery image belongs to a post.
    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    }

}
```

My create.blade.php template to post the post itself

```
@extends('layouts.scaffold')

@section('main')

<h1>Create Post</h1>

{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'posts.store', 'files' => true)) }}
    <ul>
        <li>
            {{ Form::label('title', 'Title:') }}
            {{ Form::text('title') }}
        </li>

        <li>
            {{ Form::label('body', 'Body:') }}
            {{ Form::textarea('body') }}
        </li>

        <li>
            {{ Form::file('picture') }}
        </li>
        <li>
            {{ Form::file( 'photo[]', ['multiple' => true] ) }}
        </li>

        <li>
            {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}

    </ul>
{{ Form::close() }}

@if ($errors->any())
    <ul>
        {{ implode('', $errors->all('<li class="error">:message</li>')) }}
    </ul>
@endif

@stop
```

When I post the form with a single images attached its fine and saves to the db and it works a treat but when I save it with multiple image uploads I get this error:

```
ErrorException
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array
```

The full stack trace is [here](https://gist.github.com/mdunbavan/8731592) in my gist of the files

Can anyone point out to me why this error happens. From my research its creating a multidimensional array that needs flattening I think but I am unsure if this is true.

I have been banging my head against a brick wall with this for ages.

Comment: Have you tried a dd() on the "multidimensional array that needs flattening" to see what is there? Sounds like your solution is in that array somewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem is when your submitting multiple images it becomes an array of pictures instead of a single string. So its trying to save an array to the database instead of a string which its expecting. If you make it so your photo variable is a json_encoded array of pictures then you should be able to save them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would that look and where does this take place?

Comment: i guess here $user->galleryImages()->save(json_encode($galleryImage));