# Laravel Eloquent PostgreSQL save array Error : preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, laravel-4, eloquent

I'am working on Laravel 4 and Postgresql.
I'am trying to store an array in Postgresql array field.
Here's my table declaration :

```
CREATE TABLE person_title (
    id serial primary key,
    title text,
    name_list text[]
);
```

I try to insert a line using Eloquent :

```
public function create_person_title() {
    $title = Input::get('title');
    $name_list = Input::get('name_list');
    $data = [
        'title' : $title,
        'name_list' : $name_list,
    ];
    PersonTitle::create($data);
}
```

I get this error :

```
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array
```

This error come from **vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:990** line.

I read on this question [why do I get preg_replace() error when submitting a post form in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486263/why-do-i-get-preg-replace-error-when-submitting-a-post-form-in-laravel) that this error occurs when we try to save an array.

But I really want to store an array on my Postgresql record (and I should be able to do that).
Do you know a way to do that ?

Comment: can you please post your view also ? I think you are sending array input from view and trying to save without foreach loop .

Comment: That exactly that I tried button even when I try to save raw PHP array it fails with the same error.

Comment: if your input has array then you should use foreach save the data in the database .

Comment: so please post your view here

Comment: I found a solution. I added the view named **create_person_title**. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: great (y) . Happy Coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to store array in postgresql array text field by modify my list. Here is my new view :

```
public function create_person_title() {
    $title = Input::get('title');
    $name_list = Input::get('name_list');

    // Can't save a null value
    if (!$name_list) {
        $name_list = [];
    }

    $name_list = json_encode($name_list);
    $name_list = "'".preg_replace("#^\[(.*)\]$#", '{\1}', $name_list)."'";
    $name_list = DB::raw($name_list);

    $data = [
        'title' : $title,
        'name_list' : $name_list,
    ];
    PersonTitle::create($data);
}
```

I hope it will help you.
Be careful if your array contains single quotes and others caracters like back slashes, you must escape them.

If nobody has a better way, I'm a buyer !